# Connection to Cassandra from spark Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am using Spark 2.0.2 and Cassandra 3.11.2 I am using this code but it give me connection error.

```
./spark-shell --jars ~/spark/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/target/full/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-2.0.5-121-g1a7fa1f8.jar
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

 val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
val test = sc.cassandraTable("sensorkeyspace", "sensortable")
test.count
```

When I enter test.count command it give me this error.

> java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9042
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:168)
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the yaml file? It seems the number of enough concurrent connections are open at any instance of time.

Comment: There is nothing in Yaml File I did not add anything.

Comment: Can you check for the dependency version that you are using? A mismatch may cause the issue.

Comment: What that ? I am new to spark

Comment: If you are using maven, check for the cassandra-connector dependency that you are using. Maybe you are using a version which doesn't support Cassandra 3.11.2

Comment: i am not using maven, i just install spark and install casaandra and connect both of them.

Comment: Are you sure Cassandra is on and is listening on localhost?